# Mint apt showing old packages

Tags: linux-mint, apt, repository

I currently have Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit installed. When I search for an app with apt (`apt show [package name]`) it often happens that the version available is outdated, even though apt says it's getting its packages from Ubuntu repos, which I know to be up to date from https://packages.ubuntu.com/. For example `apt show terminator` shows me `Version: 0.98-1` whereas Ubuntu site shows `1.91-1`. This has happened on a number of different packages, so how can I force apt to install the latest version?

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get upgrade && apt-get update `? Your packages also can be outdated due some dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and all dependencies seem to be up to date, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint 18.*x* releases are [based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2975), so you only get the versions of packages which are made available in 16.04 (plus whatever packages are added or upgraded in Mint itself).

Thus for Terminator, you get 0.98-1 — see [the Xenial Xerus entries](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator) — and not 1.91-1, which is only available in Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. If you want newer packages you should [upgrade to Linux Mint 19](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3615), which is based on Ubuntu 18.04.